# Hessian of $g(t,x) = t^2 - x^Tx$

Tags: derivatives

We want to find Hessian of the given function: $g(t,x) = t^2 - x^Tx$.

My answer is $0$. I was wondering if its correct or not. Can anyone please verify it? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it is  $0$? Actually even its first entry, $\nabla_{tt} g=2$ is different from $0$.

Comment: $f'$ of $x^Tx$ = $2x^T$. and $f''$ of $2x^T$ is $2$?

Comment: Yes, but if you are meaning by $f'$ $\nabla_x g$, and by $f''$ the hessian in the $x$ coordinates of $g$. So, it seems to me that then the hessian of $g$ is the diagonal Matrix with $2$ on the first entry and $-2$ in the other entries of the diagonal.